# Android - LiveData is not unsubscribed when fragment is refreshed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-livedata

So I have a weird scenario. I implemented an app which has a single Activity and two fragments. Both fragments have a filter option where they can select a category.

Based on the category, the current fragment will refresh & fetch data with the new category.

I am using ViewModel to fetch the data and LiveData to observe the changes.

My [Fragment](https://github.com/anitaa1990/TrailersApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/an/trailers/ui/main/fragment/MovieListFragment.java) class and My [ViewModel](https://github.com/anitaa1990/TrailersApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/an/trailers/ui/main/viewmodel/MovieListViewModel.java) class

```
When a button is clicked in the Activity class, this method is called:
public static void replaceFragment(Activity activity,
                                       int navId,
                                       int selectedPosition) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(INTENT_CATEGORY, selectedPosition);
        Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.fragment_nav_host)
                .navigate(navId, bundle, new NavOptions.Builder()
                        .setEnterAnim(R.anim.flip_right_in)
                        .setExitAnim(R.anim.flip_right_out)
                        .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.flip_left_in)
                        .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.flip_left_out)
                        .build());
    }
```

I am using Navigation component. So the weird issue is that when I am refreshing the fragment, the LiveData is called multiple times. I understand that when the fragment is recreated or refreshed, the viewModel instance is still the same. But not sure why this issue is happening.

If anyone can help clear this issue, would be grateful.

The entire app code can be found [here](https://github.com/anitaa1990/TrailersApp)

**UPDATE:**
So if I change my initialiseViewModel() method from:

```
private void initialiseViewModel() {
    moviesListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MovieListViewModel.class);
    moviesListViewModel.fetchMovies(MENU_MOVIE_ITEM.get(getArguments() == null ? 0: getArguments().getInt(INTENT_CATEGORY)));
    moviesListViewModel.getMoviesLiveData().observe(this, resource -> {
        if(resource.isLoading()) {
            displayLoader();

        } else if(resource.data != null && !resource.data.isEmpty()) {
            handleSuccessResponse(resource.data);

        } else handleErrorResponse();
    });
}
```

TO

```
    private void initialiseViewModel() {

        AppDatabase appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(getContext(),
                AppDatabase.class, "Entertainment.db")
                .allowMainThreadQueries().build();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor());
        httpClient.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        MovieApiService movieApiService =
                new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().create()))
                        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .client(httpClient.build())
                        .build().create(MovieApiService.class);

//        moviesListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MovieListViewModel.class);
        moviesListViewModel = new MovieListViewModel(appDatabase.movieDao(), movieApiService);
        moviesListViewModel.fetchMovies(MENU_MOVIE_ITEM.get(getArguments() == null ? 0: getArguments().getInt(INTENT_CATEGORY)));
        moviesListViewModel.getMoviesLiveData().observe(this, resource -> {
            if(resource.isLoading()) {
                displayLoader();

            } else if(resource.data != null && !resource.data.isEmpty()) {
                handleSuccessResponse(resource.data);

            } else handleErrorResponse();
        });
    }
```

then the issue seems to go away :(. Any pointers as to why?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I am refreshing the fragment" and how many times do you get change notification: two, more, or it's random?

Comment: The first time I refresh it is 3 times. The next time it is 5 and it keeps increasing.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe try to pass `getViewLifecycleOwner()` when you subscribe to LiveData instead of the Fragment itself.

Comment: I did try that. Still got the same result though

Comment: As far as i understand you inject VM? Try to use MyViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);

Comment: @anitaamurthy, what do you mean by "refresh Fragment"?

Comment: @andriy, i need to pass dao and api service class to the viewmodel. So if I cannot use this.

Comment: @Vasiliy I have a button that allows user to select category. The same fragment will be loaded again but with a new category.

Comment: I see. Might it be the case that the new Fragment is added on top of the old one and both are kept? That would explain it.

Comment: I am using setClearTop to true which means that the previous fragment is cleared. Also i checked whether onDestroy is called and it is

Comment: try to unsubscribe onStop to check? Maybe fragment isnt visible but held in memory.

Comment: I did. Not working :(

Comment: @anitaamurthy, based on the description of the issue, it really looks like your Fragments stick around. I have never used Navigation, so can't really help, but maybe you can add logging messages to `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` and make sure that the Fragments are being destroyed as you replace them?